# How to render rails partial from presenter layer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Well, I'm into this situation as well now using rails `3.2.1`
Following is the presenter in `app/presenters/form_presenter.rb`

```
class FormPresenter
  def render_form
    ActionView::Base.new.render partial: "passions/add_form"
  end
end
```

From the view I'm calling,

```
...
= AddFormPresenter.new.render_form
...
```

But it blows with the following error:

```
13:14:12 ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing partial passions/passion_concept_add_form with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :slim, :coffee, :rabl]}. Searched in:
...
```

There is this similar question at [RAILS-3.1 render method for ActionView::Base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962811/rails-3-1-render-method-for-actionviewbase) but its not helpful.

How to render this partial from the presenter layer?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I just did it by grabbing the view context using a before filter. My reference was this: https://github.com/amatsuda/active_decorator/blob/master/lib/active_decorator/view_context.rb

So something like:

```
class FormPresenter
  def render_form
    FromPresenter.view_context.render partial: "passions/add_form"
  end

  class << self
    def view_context
      Thread.current[:view_context]
    end

    def view_context=(view_context)
      Thread.current[:view_context] = view_context
    end
  end

  module Controller
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      before_filter do |controller|
        FormPresenter.view_context = controller.view_context
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and in application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
...
   include FormPresenter::Controller
...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't typical of the presenter pattern. Presenters are for centralizing complicated data and logic needed to simpify the view's rendering task. Here you are rendering inside the presenter.  Is this really what you intend?

Say the answer is yes.  Then just creating a new `ActionView::Base` is asking for trouble because initializing it is non-trivial [as shown here](http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/517-How-to-render-a-view-or-partial-from-a-Rake-task-model-or-anywhere).  Something strange is going on with class or some other kind of nesting.  Where did the `passion_concept_` prefix come from in the error message?  It looks like you're not telling us all we need about your app.

You may find joy by telling the presenter explicitly where it's rendering:

```
class FormPresenter

  def self.render_form(view)
    view.render partial: "passions/add_form"
  end

end
```

Then in the view:

```
= FormPresenter.render_form(self)
```

(Here again the explanation is not clear.  What is `AddFormPresenter`?) I don't have a machine where I can try this at the moment, but it ought to be more debuggable than what you've got.